# Creating Dynamic class in JAVA without using reflection API?

Tags: java, string, class, generics, io

I created a java class file Dynamically by passing data type and field name to my method. Now I want to pass the same values Dynamically (from Console) how can I do.

Below is My Code:

```
public class MapFirst {
public static void createClass(String className,
        Map<Class<?>, String> fields) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String packageName;
    int idx = className.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (idx >= 0) {
        packageName = className.substring(0, idx);
        className = className.substring(idx + 1);
    } else
        packageName = null;

    if (packageName != null)
        builder.append("package ").append(packageName).append(";\n");

    builder.append("\n");

    builder.append("public class ").append(className).append("\n");

    builder.append("{\n");

    boolean flag = false;
    for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, String> field : fields.entrySet()) {
        Class<?> type = field.getKey();
        String name = field.getValue();
        String nameCapitalized = Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0))
                + name.substring(1);

        if (flag)
            builder.append("\n");
        flag = true;
        builder.append("    private ").append(type).append(" ")
                .append(name).append(";\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("    public ").append(type).append(" get")
                .append(nameCapitalized).append(" ()\n");
        builder.append("    {\n");
        builder.append("        return ").append(name).append(";\n");
        builder.append("    }\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("    public void set").append(nameCapitalized)
                .append(" (").append(type).append(" ").append(name)
                .append(")\n");
        builder.append("    {\n");
        builder.append("        this.").append(name).append(" = ")
                .append(name).append(";\n");
        builder.append("    }\n");
    }

    builder.append("}\n");

    File dir = new File(packageName.replaceAll("\\.",
            Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("file.separator"))));

    dir.mkdirs();

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, className + ".java"))));

    writer.write(builder.toString());
    writer.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<Class<?>, String> fields = new HashMap<Class<?>, String>();
    fields.put(int.class, "foo");
    fields.put(double.class, "bar"); // I wnat to pass these values from console
    fields.put(char.class, "me");
    fields.put(int.class, "i");
    createClass("my.pkg.MyClass1", fields);
}
}
```

Now I want pass those values Dynamically how Can I do.

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this? As much as I hate them, a `Map` might be a better option here.

Answer (score 2):

Since the class is not known at compile time the only way to access it is by reflection.

I don't know how you have written `createClass` but if you manage to create a class that extends another class known at compile time then you can use polymorphism to access its *`methods`* without reflection.

Comment: I am afraid I am unable to understand your question due to language issues. Can you please update your question with sample code of what you would like to do?

Comment: sure @Miserable Variable

Comment: So `createClass` just creates a source file. How does it get compiled? You will need to run `javac` on it, and ensure that the generated `.class` file is in `classpath`. Irrespective of that, I don't see how you can access its members without reflection.

Comment: So there is no way to create a java class  without reflection

Comment: So far you have not even created a class, you have only written a source file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one exception where I would advise to revert to JavaScript or BeanShell (java like scripting) or so. Interoperation with java can be done with the Java Scripting API.

However maybe [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) (AOP/byte code) may be what you are searching for, though complex.

Comment: thank you @Joop Eggen
I got the result, But instead of passing field type (int.class,..) I want to read from console that's i want.